# Microsoft Reporting Services - How do you default parameter values, but not display the report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm using Reporting Services 2012. It seems it displays the report unconditionally if you have default values specified in all report parameters. If you specify no default value for any one parameter it doesn't display by default.

Anyone know of a way to default values, but not display the report?

Comment: If you are using procedures in SQL Server you could parse the execution time, and userid of the person running the report.  If this is the first instance the report has been run within the last minute, then return nothing, otherwise return the data for the report.  I use the reverse of this method to cache the data of a report for 5 minutes, in case it gets hit hard during a busy spell.  Its not on a dedicated report server with automated caching. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come across the same problem before, which certainly became an issue when the default parameters returned a very large number of results.  It took a long time for the report to render, only for the user to instantly want to change the defaults and run it again.

Unfortunately the only way around this I discovered was to add a new "Run Report" parameter, that had no default value.  The report would display all the other default values, but not the report itself.  The end user then had to set "Run Report" to "Yes" to actually render the report, as only at this point was the final parameter set.

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks